# Return Current Connection CName

Tags: sql-server, dns

I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to return the name that was used to connect to the SQL server rather than the actual server's name. For instance I typically connect to the server via a DNS CName. But if I run this ..

```
select @@SERVERNAME
```

... I get the actual server name. I'm looking to find a way to get the CName with which I connected if it is even possible. Thoughts?

Comment: If you could give some background about why you want to do this, someone might be able to come up with an alternative way to accomplish your goal. For example, if you have control of the clients, you can have them pass something in the Application Name part of the connection string. You could then access that -- for example in the ProgramName column of sp_who2.

Comment: You could add multiple IP addresses to the server and map each name to a different IP address.

Comment: @DougDeden I like the thought about passing the value in the connection string. I'll think about that a bit. I could potentially pass it in the connection string, parse that SQL Server side, and then compare. I'm creating an SSIS job that will gather all sorts of SQL data from our servers and centralize it into a place where I can easily report on it. The SSIS package loops through a table with SQL server names. I want to make sure that any servers put into the table are the actual names not CNames. If it is a CName I'll send out an alert when the job runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL Server instance has no notion of the name resolution the client used to connect to the server IP address so what you want is not possible.

[`@@SERVERNAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql) returns the server name or FCI network name, plus instance name for a named instance. The value is unrelated to the client connection specification.

Comment: My guess with **SSMS** (which does display the name used to connect, whether it's a **CNAME** or whatever) is just taking it from what the user entered in the Login window I suppose, eh?

Comment: @J.D. I agree. The name that SSMS shows in the Object Explorer and the status bar of query windows seems to be determined by the client, and not by the server.